# What is the best way to care about assertion fail in Eigen C++?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a question what the best way is to care about assertion fail in Eigen C++.
I know if there were wrong matrix calculation, Eigen stops program by assertion fail.
For example,

```
MatrixXf a(2, 2);
MatrixXf b(1, 1);
MatrixXf c = a + b;
```

In this case, the size of matrix a and b is difference, so assertion fails occurs.
Then what is the best way to avoid it ?

I can avoid, if I checked matrix size at every time before calculating.

```
MatrixXf a(2, 2);
MatrixXf b(1, 1);
MatrixXf c;
if (a.cols() == b.cols() && a.rows() == b.rows()) {
    c = a + b;
}
```

But I think it's not smart way, checking each calculation.

Is there any better way to check it ? 
Could I catch exception by using try-catch ? Or does Eigen have any check function ?

Comment: If your program hits the assertion failure, it has a logic error and you should fix it. There is no sense in trying to continue. Your `if` check ostensibly works, but do you have a plan of what to do in the `else` part? (Other than print a message and exit).

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I'll take care of logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can predefine the `eigen_assert` macro to throw an exception instead of asserting. E.g.:

```
#define eigen_assert(X) do { if(!(X)) throw std::runtime_error(#X); } while(false);
// make sure Eigen is not included before your define:
#include <Eigen/Core>
```

But as @n.m. pointed out, you should rather fix your logic error, i.e., you should not try to add matrices if you are not sure that their sizes match.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. It worked well. But I'll take care of logic before using this macro.